# Flutter location doesn't return data after use onLocationChanged

Tags: flutter, location, getlocation

I have two separate screen `home.dart` and `track.dart`

In `home.dart`

```
location.getLocation()
```

In `track.dart` I'm listening location

```
location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData loc) { // do something })
```

When I navigate to `track.dart` screen and return to `home.dart` location.getLocation doesn't return any data and not giving any error at all.

How can I implement such feature and what is the best solution for this problem.

Flatform: android
Flutter location version: 4.3.0

Comment: Can you share the code sample? Where do you call `location.getLocation()` ?

Comment: Calling after initState

Comment: If you're calling it somewhere within `initState`, then that's probably why. Unless you're pushing a new home screen on the Navigator stack, your home screen already exists, and any code that's called in `initState` is only triggered once, when the widget is created. You probably want to move that code to `didChangeDependencies` instead.

Comment: @DavidL. I have check and confirm that location.getLocation()  being calling.